# Compile latex project on Linux through CLI

Tags: latex, pdf-generation

I'm trying to compile and automate the process of generating the PDF from this project [https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume][1] on Linux machine(Ubuntu specifically). I'm finding it quite difficult to compile. I've tried different compilers but it always ends in errors and warnings.

Edit 1:
command run to create file:
`xetex deedy_resume-openfont.xtx`

log file output:

````
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**deedy_resume-openfont.xtx
(./deedy_resume-openfont.xtx
! Undefined control sequence.
l.48 \documentclass
                   []{deedy-resume-openfont}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.49 \usepackage
                {fancyhdr}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.51 \pagestyle
               {fancy}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.52 \fancyhf
             {}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.54 \begin
           {document}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.61 \lastupdated

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.68 \namesection
                 {Debarghya}{Das}{ \urlstyle{same}\href{http://debarghyadas....

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.68 \namesection{Debarghya}{Das}{ \urlstyle
                                            {same}\href{http://debarghyadas....

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.68 ...tion{Debarghya}{Das}{ \urlstyle{same}\href
                                                  {http://debarghyadas.com}{...

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.68 ...debarghyadas.com}{debarghyadas.com}| \href
                                                  {http://fb.co/dd}{fb.co/dd}\\

? 
! Argument of \\ has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.70 }

? 
Runaway argument?
 \href {mailto:deedy@fb.com}{deedy@fb.com} | 607.379.5733 | \href {ma\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \\ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
<to be read again> 
                   }
l.70 }

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.78 \begin
           {minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.78 \begin{minipage}[t]{0.33\textwidth
                                       }
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.84 \section
             {Education}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.86 \subsection
                {Cornell University}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.87 \descript
              {MEng in Computer Science}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.88 \location
              {Dec 2014 | Ithaca, NY}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.89 \sectionsep

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.91 \subsection
                {Cornell University}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.92 \descript
              {BS in Computer Science}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.93 \location
              {May 2014 | Ithaca, NY}
? 
Runaway argument?
 Magna Cum Laude\\ \location { Cum. GPA: 3.83 / 4.0 \\ Major GPA: 3.9\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \\ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.99 

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.100 \subsection
                 {La Martiniere for Boys}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.101 \location
               {Grad. May 2011|  Kolkata, India}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.102 \sectionsep

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.108 \section
              {Links}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.109 Facebook:// \href
                       {https://facebook/dd}{\bf dd} \\
? 
Runaway argument?
 Github:// \href {https://github.com/deedydas}{\bf deedydas} \\ Linke\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \\ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.115 

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.120 \section
              {Coursework}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.121 \subsection
                 {Graduate}
? 
Runaway argument?
 Open Source Software Engineering \\ Advanced Interactive Graphics \\\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \\ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.131 

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.132 \subsection
                 {Undergraduate}
? 
Runaway argument?
 Operating Systems \\ Artificial Intelligence + Practicum \\ Function\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \\ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.140 

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.145 \section
              {Skills}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.146 \subsection
                 {Programming}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.147 \location
               {Over 5000 lines:}
? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.148 Java \textbullet
                      {}   Shell \textbullet{} Python \textbullet{} Javascri...

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.148 Java \textbullet{}   Shell \textbullet
                                            {} Python \textbullet{} Javascri...

? 
! Undefined control sequence.
l.148 ...   Shell \textbullet{} Python \textbullet
                                                  {} Javascript \\
? 
Runaway argument?
 OCaml \textbullet {} Matlab \textbullet {} Rails \textbullet {} \LaTeX \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \\ was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.155 

? 
[1] )
Output written on deedy_resume-openfont.pdf (1 page).```



  [1]: https://github.com/deedy/Deedy-Resume
````

Comment: "ends in errors and warnings" is not much for a diagnosis. Please show the .log file and also a [mre] of the code you try to compile.

Comment: edited my original question, added the log file and command run

Comment: you need `xelatex` and not `xetex` for compiling

Comment: Thanks for the answer it worked. The output file is almost complete. The project also contains a .bib file. The author of the project says to compile it using bibtex but it outputs a jagged output. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: "jagged output" is again not a very helpful error description. What is the command line output if you run `bibtex deedy_resume-openfont` and the .log file? And what do you consider jagged output? Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I apologize. I just looked at the source code for that section, it seems that the section contains hardcoded spaces.```\section{Publications}
\renewcommand\refname{\vskip -1.5cm}``` Fixed it using ```\renewcommand\refname{PUBLICATIONS}```Again thanks for the answer!!!